# How to load json data dynamically in external_choices

Tags: odk, odk-xform, xlsform

community. I am new in ODK forms. I just want to ask how can I load JSON data or any other way rather than JSON, in my external_choices at run time dynamically.
Example: I want to load data based on district_id. In my one district, there are 2000 villages, and I have 40 districts in my state. Feeding 40*2000=80000 villages in external_choices and loading it at run time is very ram consuming. So in my case, I'll just want to pass the district_id in my query parameter and villages belonging to that district will be fetched from JSON and loaded into external_choices. Can anybody help how I can achieve it?